# Is each form of word classification also considered to be '(named) entity recognition'?

Tags: classification, nlp, named-entity-recognition

In an article that I am writing, I focus on word classification. A typical task that involves word classification is (named) entity recognition. Entity recognition is a rather broad task and seems to cover other sub-tasks as well.

Therefore, it seems fair to me to use the terms interchangeably.

Is this a fair assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a fair assumption?

No: Named Entity Recognition (NER) is a specific task which consists in detecting [named entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_entity). The more general term for this kind of task in Machine Learning is [sequence labelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_labeling), because it's not only about classifying words but annotating a sequence of instances in which order matters (e.g. words).

It's true that NER is certainly the most famous task of this kind, but there are other important ones, for instance [Part-Of-Speech (POS) tagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging).